# Default argument promotions in C99 standard

Tags: c, function, prototype, c99, promotions

I have a question about default argument promotions in C99 standard. In the book "C Programming - A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition" I've read that:

> **Argument Conversions:**
>
> [...]
>
> 1) **The compiler has encountered a prototype prior to the call.** [...]
>
> 2) **The compiler has not encountered a prototype prior to the call**. The compiler performs the default argument promotions: (1)`float`arguments are converted to`double`. (2) The integral promotions are performed, causing`char`and`short`arguments to be converted to`int`. (*In C99, the integer promotions are performed.*)

A few lines further is shown an example in which there is no function prototype or definition before calling it. It is commented as follows:

> Of course, a much better solution is to provide a prototype for`square`before calling it. *In C99, calling`square`without first providing a declaration or definition of the function is an error.*

Aren't those two cursive sentences kind of contrary with each other? I mean, if C99 forbids calling functions without previous declaration/definition how can it determine promotions in that kind of function call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No they are not contradictory.

A declaration is not necessarily a prototype:

```
int f();
```

declares the function `f` but isn't a prototype since nothing is known about the argument types.

```
int (a)
 in a;
{
 ...
}
```

is a definition but isn't a prototype either.

Answer (score 2):

C99 does not forbid you to call functions that have no prototype.

I can't give the details because you have not posted code for `square()` or the call to it, but presumably what is happening is that the promotion made to the arguments in the call to `square()` result in different types being passed to the function than it actually declares in the implementation.

*That's* what would result in undefined behavior, and would be an error.

For example:

```
// in foo.c:

int foo(void)
{ 
    char x = 42;

    return square(x); // x is promoted to int, but is wrong
}


// in bar.c

#include <stdio.h>
void bar(int x)
{ 
    square( &x); // this call is fine -  what is being passed is what square() expects
    printf("The result is %d\n", x);
}


// in square.c

void square( int* p)
{
    *p *= *p;
    return;
}
```

And if `square()` is defined with a prototype that declares the parameter to have an argument of type `char`, there's no way to call correctly it without a prototype having been 'seen' by the calling code since in such cases the argument will be promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find anything about it being an error of calling a function without providing a prior declaration or definition in C99.

The closes thing seems to be that the default return type of int is no longer assumed. i.e. the declaration `foo(int a);` is allowed pre-C99, but an error in C99. pre-C99 it'd mean `int foo(int a);`